# Воспроизвести открывок из аудио

Tags: java, android, android-mediaplayer

Недавно узнал что на `JS` можно воспроизводить определённый кусок `mp3`, то есть, например, есть аудио файл длительностью 30 секунд и есть три кнопки, по нажатию на первую кнопку аудио воспроизводится с 1 по 10 секунду, нажатием на вторую с 11 по 20, ну и с третьей соответственно с 21 по 30. Возможно ли такое в `Java`?